# Remove water ways and 'hug' the shores of polygon (postal boundaries)

Tags: geotools, jts-topology-suite, postal-code

[image]

I am trying to produce postal polygons that 'hug' the mainland instead of the polygon overlapping bodies of water.  What is a good way to accomplish this?

I've tried searching for 'water ways' polygons and perhaps use that to recreate the postal polygon with the water-ways removed via JTS/GeoTools. But cannot find all waterways  geospaital file...

In the image you can see the shore of the polygon representing 3516 includes the 'water' area...I want to clip the water out of the polygons (via JTS/GeoTools).

Comment: This seems like a question that warrants the "why do you want to do this" question. There are lots of ways to go about what you're asking but they're all going to be imperfect in some way...and it seems like this whole effort might be unnecessary. You can use OSM (check out Overpass API) to fetch waterway polygons from Openstreetmap--quality might be varying and not align with your basemap, though.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You really need to add the code too?

Comment: lol downvote, classic... Can't even ask a question!  Anyways..@Jon that's interesting, I checked out OSM and do see the waterway polygons I believe I could use this to do what i want... thanks.

Comment: You are always welcome to "ask a question" but we do like them to be clear questions with a code attempt if they are a programming question. Are you really looking for code or just a general algorithmic approach?